# WPF- Need updated point values of polygon after applying render transform

Tags: wpf, graphics, geometry, polygon

I need to add labels for vertices of triangle that is created using polygon in WPF and labels should move according to triangle. I have initial points of vertices (0,0), (0,100) & (100,100) but it does not change after applying render transform (rotate, scale & translate).
So, please help me to calculate new coordinates of polygon (triangle in this example).

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="450"
    Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Polygon
                Points="0,0 0,100 100,100"           
                Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness="1"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <!--<ScaleTransform
                            ScaleX="5" />-->
                        <!--<TranslateTransform
                            X="20"
                            Y="20" />-->
                        <!--<RotateTransform
                            Angle="45" />-->
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Polygon.RenderTransform>
            </Polygon>
            <Label Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Content="V1" />
            <Label
                Canvas.Left="0"
                Canvas.Top="100"
                Content="V2" />
            <Label
                Canvas.Left="100"
                Canvas.Top="100"
                Content="V3" />
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to transform the Polygon by its RenderTransform? Doing so would also scale its StrokeThickness. You may consider using a Path with a PathGeometry where you add a PolyLineSegment, and set the PathGeometry's Transform property.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens for quick reply but I have no issue with change in StrokeThickness.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to pass already transformed points to the Points collection of the Polygon. You could then easily bind to their coordinates like `Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=polygon, Path=Points[0].X}"`